# OCaml warning error spurious line number

Tags: ocaml

When I have a file `foo.ml`:

```
let foo = [];;

let bar =
  match [] with
  | [] -> [];;
```

and I try to have the missing match case on line 4 be flagged as an error:

```
#warn_error "+8";;
#use "foo.ml";;
```

I get a spurious line reference to line 1 just before the end of the ouput of my `#use`:

```
val foo : 'a list = []
File "foo.ml", line 4, characters 2-26:
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
_::_
File "foo.ml", line 1:
Error: Some fatal warnings were triggered (1 occurrences)
```

This is of course not a real problem, but I still find the spurious line reference irritating. Is there some way to convince OCaml not to print that irrelevant `File "foo.ml", line 1:` line in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is just how the compiler works. You can find the source code of this feature in [parsing/location.ml](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/4.04.0/parsing/location.ml). The way fatal warnings are implemented is by building an error message relative to the file itself:

```
| Warnings.Errors n ->
    Some
      (errorf ~loc:(in_file !input_name)
      "Some fatal warnings were triggered (%d occurrences)" n)
```

The `in_file` function is why you are seeing "line 1":

```
let in_file name =
  let loc = {
    pos_fname = name;
    pos_lnum = 1;
    pos_bol = 0;
    pos_cnum = -1;
  } in
  { loc_start = loc; loc_end = loc; loc_ghost = true }
```

This data type lacks a way to represent a location which as a filename but no line number.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had found that code already too. I think there is something that if the filename is `"//toplevel//"` then the line is not printed. I wondered if maybe I could hack things a bit to exploit that to repress this line, but I guess it will not work.

Comment: It seems that there is [a fix in the works](https://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6112).

Comment: Étienne: very nice, thanks for pointing this out! I'll wait patiently :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's complettely spurious. It's referring to a fact about the file as a whole. They had to pick some line to represent the whole file.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. Still, it is distracting: my eye goes to the end of the output to find in what line my problem is, and then there is an irrelevant line number there.  So there is nothing that can be done about this?